# Sitecore item auto sync from Prod to DEV & QA environment

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to schedule content sync from Prod to QA and DEV environment so while doing search I found following post:

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/2438

But I do have further queries on this. Please suggest.

1. Do we need license for target server also ( QA & DEV ) also OR only once license is required from where( Prod ) we are actually sending content.
2. As we know we can run script( Razl.exe /script:"c:\Site Migration\Razl.xml" ) manually from cmd command but is there any way we can schedule weekly basis.

Comment: That's two very separate questions. Please split this into two posts.

Comment: I agree, this is really two separate questions, and seems like you're asking specifically about licensing info for Razl, which is better asked probably of Hedgehog. In addition, the second question is more of a ServerFault question than a Sitecore question.  If you have a command, you can always schedule a windows task to run.

Comment: This is not necessarily the only options. If you were to re-word your question asking for "recommendations for syncing PROD -> QA/DEV" then you may get something more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAZL licensing is best handled through Hedgehog's sales team (sales@hhogdev.com).

I believe that the licensing depends on where the instance of Razl is installed. i.e You could run it from your own machine, and have connections to PROD, QA and DEV, but make the execution of the script run from your own machine running your own license. However this means all transfers are across the wire....whereas if it were running on one of the servers, you might find some performance boost.

But for running locally, you also still maintain usage of Razl's UI for:-
 - comparison
 - filtering
 - link-navigating
 - granular copy controls
 - and script-generation capabilities

On top of that, for the case you mention, consistent content migration is best done with Razl's History Syncing (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRAWCvtsavg&list=PLb9QmtmxCbhm5RnL42g1Trmr9-z_ZP40J&index=11) which is also available in your scripts (and probably what you should be using for a scheduled weekly-sync).

To setup a scheduled weekly sync, create a Windows task that executes weekly, running `Razl.exe /script:"c:\Site Migration\Razl.xml"`.

Answer (score 1):

In light of what jammykam is saying above another option is Sitecore Sidekick's content migrator:

https://jeffdarchuk.com/2016/10/24/sitecore-sidekick-content-migrator/

It's a free open source angular module that is installed in Sitecore. We're using it and it works really well to sync content down from Prod to Dev and Staging etc.

[image]

At the moment I don't think it supports a scheduled auto-migration but I've messaged Jeff Darchuk to ask if this is possible in future versions as it's something I'd be really interested in also.

Either way it would be good to re-word your question so it's not multiple questions in one.

Comment: thanks Adam for sharing this and it's good tool but we have requirement for auto scheduling...will keep an eyes on this also